# Error al leer Json en Android

Tags: java, android, json

Estoy tratando de leer este Json que contiene arreglos, pero me da el siguiente error, lo estoy leyendo con JSONArray, intenté recorrerlo con un `for` pero no me deja extraer los objetos dentro del json. ¿alguien sabe que puedo hacer o que estoy haciendo mal?

```
12-05 09:56:59.051 16157-16157/pubeat.app.version1_0 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"Cerca de ti":{"nombre":"Cerca de ti","promos":[{"prom_id":"21","neg_id":"3","prom_desc":"prmo especial","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=21","neg_nombre":"Alitas Wings Consti","vip":"0","calificacion":"4","distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"9","neg_id":"3","prom_desc":"chelas 2x1 todos los viernes","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=9","neg_nombre":"Alitas Wings Consti","vip":"0","calificacion":"4","distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"18","neg_id":"12","prom_desc":"promo para ffff","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=18","neg_nombre":"fffffff","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"}]},"Recomendadas":{"nombre":"Recomendadas","promos":[]},"Mas Populares":{"nombre":"Mas Populares","promos":[{"prom_id":"15","neg_id":"9","prom_desc":"promociones por hora","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=15","neg_nombre":"Wings Tesistan","vip":"0","calificacion":"5","distancia":null},{"prom_id":"21","neg_id":"3","prom_desc":"prmo especial","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=21","neg_nombre":"Alitas Wings Consti","vip":"0","calificacion":"4","distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"9","neg_id":"3","prom_desc":"chelas 2x1 todos los viernes","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=9","neg_nombre":"Alitas Wings Consti","vip":"0","calificacion":"4","distancia":"0"}]},"Promos Decembrinas":{"nombre":"Promos Decembrinas","promos":[{"prom_id":"22","neg_id":"9","prom_desc":"programa tus posadas para este año","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=22","neg_nombre":"Wings Tesistan","vip":"0","calificacion":"5","distancia":null},{"prom_id":"22","neg_id":"9","prom_desc":"programa tus posadas para este año","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=22","neg_nombre":"Wings Tesistan","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":null}]},"Promociones Hallowen":{"nombre":"Promociones Hallowen","promos":[{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"9","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"Wings Tesistan","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":null},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"66","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio58","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"101","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio93","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"10","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"Wings Army ","vip":"0","calificacion":"5","distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"46","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio38","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"81","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio73","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"26","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio18","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"61","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio53","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"96","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","logo":"https:\/\/pubeat.com.mx\/pubeat\/system\/ajax\/Logo.php?prom_id=20","neg_nombre":"minegocio88","vip":"0","calificacion":null,"distancia":"0"},{"prom_id":"20","neg_id":"131","prom_desc":"promo de hallowen","
12-05 09:56:59.051 16157-16157/pubeat.app.version1_0 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
12-05 09:56:59.051 16157-16157/pubeat.app.version1_0 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
12-05 09:56:59.051 16157-16157/pubeat.app.version1_0 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
12-05 09:56:59.051 16157-16157/pubeat.app.version1_0 W/System.err:     at pubeat.app.version1_0.PromosCardViewFragment$1.onResponse(PromosCardViewFragment.java:59)
12-05 09:56:59.051 16157-16157/pubeat.app.version1_0 W/System.err:     at pubeat.app.version1_0.PromosCardViewFragment$1.onResponse(PromosCardViewFragment.java:52)
```

El código es:

```
public class PromosCardViewFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<FuentePromosInfo> listaFuenteInfo;
    String imgUrl = "http://www.teorema.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/agua-vital.jpg";
    String imfUrl2 = "http://arribaelcampo.com.mx/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/agua-1.jpg";

    public PromosCardViewFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //Creamos las variables en donde se guardará el url de la imagen obtenida del json


        //Creamos arreglo para poblar CardViews de promos con las imagenes
        listaFuenteInfo = new ArrayList<FuentePromosInfo>();



        Response.Listener<String> promosListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {

                    JSONArray promJson = new JSONArray(response);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), (CharSequence) promJson, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        };
        RecyclerView contenedor = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerContenedor);
        contenedor.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        contenedor.setAdapter(new PromosCardViewAdapter(listaFuenteInfo));
        contenedor.setLayoutManager(layout);


        PromosInfoRequest promosInfoRequest = new PromosInfoRequest(promosListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        queue.add(promosInfoRequest);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promos_card_view, container, false);


    }
}
```

Comment: Hola has usado alguna herramienta para dar formato al JSON y visualizar más claramente su estructura y distinguir más facilmente entre JsonArray y JsonObject? Te recomiendo las siguientes: https://jsoneditoronline.org/ https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: Consulta: puedes cambiar el formato Json desde su origen o eso no lo puedes hacer... Lo menciono porque el algoritmo para iterar sobre un JSONArray es engorroso, complejo y se presta para muchos errores... Puede ser que si el JSON se arma tomando como base tablas de una base de datos mas compleja, se pueda parsear a objetos con la librería GSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tu response no es un JSONArray, lo que estas recibiendo es un JSONObject por eso el error al momento de inicializar el JSONArray, si lo que esperas es un JSONArray como tal, te recomiendo cambiar la estructura de tu respuesta en JSON, mientras tanto aquí te dejo una solución a tu problema para que de tu respuesta puedas obtener un JSONArray, este código ya está probado con el **response** que pusiste en esta publicación

```
String response = ""; //TU RESPONSE
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        Iterator<String> iterator = jsonObject.keys();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonObject.get(key).toString());
            jsonArray.put(object);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", jsonArray.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Si tienes algún error, o alguna duda, no dudes en contestarme, saludos.

Este es un ejemplo de como puedes iterrar tu array padre y el array de promos de cada item en tu array padre.

```
        //Iterar JSONArray
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i ++){
            JSONObject item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String nombre = item.getString("nombre");
            JSONArray jsonArrayPromos = item.getJSONArray("promos");
            //Iterar JSONArrayPromos
            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayPromos.length(); j ++) {
                JSONObject itemPromo = jsonArrayPromos.getJSONObject(j);
                //Ejemplo de como extrar cada propiedad
                String prom_id = itemPromo.getString("prom_id");
                String neg_id = itemPromo.getString("neg_id");
               //...
                Log.d("TAG",  i + " " + itemPromo.toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok y utilizando tu código, una vez que ya tenga acomodado el JSONArray, ya podré extraer los objetos recorriendo el Array con un for y extraerlos con getString();?

Comment: Negativo, si recorres el array con un for, lo que obtienes de cada posición es un JSONObject, ese JSONObject (deacuerdo a tu response), contiene dos propiedades: nombre y promos, nombre es de tipo String, por lo que el metodo getString(); funcionaria en tu JSONObject, pero la segunda propiedad (promos) es un JSONArray por lo que el método getString(); no te funcionará con ella.

Comment: ok entonces podría extraer nombre con getString y luego extraigo promos como JsonArray y ese si lo recorro con un for?

Comment: Correcto, solo recuerdo crear un JSONObject en cada iteración. Editaré la respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo.

Comment: Que tal amigo, muchas gracias por el código si me funcionó solo que a la hora de imprimir por ejemplo todos los nombre que encontró, me aparecen varias veces el mismo y me fijé en mi Json y solo tengo 1 Cerca de ti por ejemplo, pero a la hora de imprimir me imprime como 4 veces Cerca de ti y luego los demás también repetidos, sabes como lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Al momento de recorrer los array, revisa en las dos iteraciones que estes usando i y j respectivamente